# Determine type of Apple device (laptop, iPhone, or iPad) that is sending mail by examining the mail headers

Tags: email, cpanel, whm, smtp, apple

I have a client who is using a laptop, iPhone, and iPad to send emails. However, after checking outgoing message queues on the server, one of the Apple devices is using the wrong settings.

Is there a way to determine if the offending device is the iPad or iPhone from the mail headers? I've already been able to determine that it's an Apple device from the headers, just not which one.

**Header 1:**

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary=Apple-Mail-B93E63C5-776C-4599-84BD-E469736CA6A9
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
From: User <user@domain.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0 (1.0)
Subject: Re: Some long subject
Message-Id: <539C3070-9C79-4CB0-B727-D4B05A9E6657@domain.com>
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2016 09:57:29 -0500
References: <0.0.AC.7C6.1D247F96FA2C31A.0@otherdomain.com> <CY4PR10MB1237B91CE974180CD4059EA0B58D0@lastdomain.com>
To: user <user@domain.com>
In-Reply-To: <CY4PR10MB1237B91CE974180CD4059EA0B58D0@lastdomain.com>

--Apple-Mail-B93E63C5-776C-4599-84BD-E469736CA6A9
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

**Header 2:**

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary=Apple-Mail-C348E374-375D-469C-9CF7-07BBDBD703CD
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
From: User <user@domain.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0 (1.0)
Date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 15:47:47 -0500
Subject: Some Subject
Message-Id: <18EB5952-1462-4DCD-93FD-CEA677C3764E@domain.com>
To: Some Person <someperson@gmail.com>

--Apple-Mail-C348E374-375D-469C-9CF7-07BBDBD703CD
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

**Header 3:**

```
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
From: User <user@domain.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0 (1.0)
Subject: Subject
Message-Id: <83AC3EE2-9B20-4534-806E-AEAA7B272DFD@domain.com>
Date: Tue, 22 Nov 2016 22:01:37 -0500
To: User <user@domain.com>
```

Comment: Can you post some of the relevant headers such as the `User-Agent`?

Comment: I have added one of the headers.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, I added two others which may help.